# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in Asp.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, linq-to-sql

I am trying to load images from the folder UploadImages combined with image name for the particular query
 my gridview code is as follows:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="50" ShowHeader="false" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetails_PageIndexChanging">
                        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <h2><asp:Label runat="server"><%#Eval("Ads_Title")%></asp:Label></h2>
                                    <h5><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ads_Posted_Date")%>'></asp:Label>, Posted by&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ads_State")%>'></asp:Label></a></h5>
                                    <div class="blog-para">
                                        <p class="para">

                                            <image src='../UploadImages/<%#Eval("Busines_Image") %>' Width="150px" />


                                            <p><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Cat_Name")%>'></asp:Label></p>
                                            <p>Pokect Listing: <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PocketListing")%>' /> </p>
                                            <p><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Ads_Hot_Normal") == "false" ? "<image src='images/premium_logo.png' alt='Premium'" : " " %>'runat="server" /></p>
                                            <div class="read_more">
                                                <a class="btn" href='AdsDetails.aspx?AddId=<%#Eval("main_ID") %>'>Read More</a>
                                            </div>
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Every time i run the webapp it states faied to load the resource.

Comment: Check the source html and path for image, you need to use correct relative path.

Comment: The file exists in the folder and the path is correct on runtime

Comment: What path you see if you look at source in browser where you open the web page. Is is complete path or relative. As the relative path can start from root directory or current page folder which you are browsing,

Comment: i can see the complete path when i look at the source in browser

Comment: What happens when you copy and paste the complete path of your image into a new browser window? If it doesn't work, the path is wrong. Using "../" in your paths can cause issues if your page is displayed in a different directory than immediately above your UploadedImages directory. Best to substitute "../" with the path from the root of your website e.g. "/parent_dirs_if_any/UploadedImages/"

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus.

Comment: @Scotty there is no parent directly to UploadImages folder

Comment: Ok easy try this then <image src='/UploadImages/<%#Eval("Busines_Image") %>' Width="150px" />

Comment: Then too the error is the same! @Scotty

Comment: Ok, there must still be a problem with the path to the image. Can you view source again, and copy paste the path to one of your images here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111076/discussion-between-aarthna-maheshwari-and-scotty).

Comment: http://localhost:51601/UploadImages/8722019k=(1).jpg here is the URL @Scotty

Answer (score 0):

This is might be happening because GridView control is losing View. For more details yo can try this [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1043999.aspx)