# Image is not displaying after adding items to the cart

Tags: c#

[image]Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

System.Byte[]:1

This error is coming on inspecting it

```
protected void AllData()

    {

        if (Session["AddProduct"].ToString() == "true")

        {
            Session["AddProduct"] = "false";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;
            
            dt.Columns.Add("ImageID");
            dt.Columns.Add("ImageName");
            dt.Columns.Add("ImageFile");
           
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");

            if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
            {
                if (Session["Buyitems"] == null)
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    string cont = @"";
                    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(cont);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    string query = "select * from tblclothes where ImageID=" + Request.QueryString["Id"];
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                     cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dr["ImageID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageID"].ToString();
                    dr["ImageName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString();
                    dr["ImageFile"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageFile"].ToString();
                    dr["Price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    gvproducts.DataSource = dt;
                    gvproducts.DataBind();
                    Session["buyitems"] = dt;
                }
```

this is the code

```
protected static string ReturnEncodedBase64UTF8(object rawImg)

    {
        string img = "data:image/jpg;base64,{0}"; //change image type if need be
        string toEncodeAsBytes = rawImg.ToString();
        string returnValue = System.Convert.ToString(toEncodeAsBytes);
        return String.Format(img, returnValue);
    }
```

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvproducts" OnRowDataBound="gvproducts_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Blue"
        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" OnRowDeleting="gvproducts_RowDeleting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        EmptyDataText="No Data Available" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" Width="400px">

    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="S.No" HeaderText="S.No" />--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageId" HeaderText="Image Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageName" HeaderText="Image Name" />
        <%--<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageFile" HeaderText="Image"></asp:ImageField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<img src='../Images/ <%# Eval("ImageFile") %>' id="img" runat="server" />--%>
                <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "data:Image/png;base64," + Eval("ImageFile") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalFormat" HeaderText="Format" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" Text="Total Price"></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please include more details of your code. 404 error means that the image is not found so you need to check if the images are there in your folder from where you are referencing them.

Comment: Would you please share the code, that is throwing the error?

Comment: @ShubhamRiyal Please do not post images of the code. Rather post the code here to get better responses.

Comment: check your database and the related table if the specified field name have 'S' and remove it manually and check again.

Comment: PLease check now why the image is not binding and why the error is appearing : System.Byte[]:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). And the ImageFile field is of varbinary(MAX) datatype in the table and in code it is byte[].

Comment: And i did not upload the image from any webpage...I have inserted the image directly to the table

Comment: @Rahul Sharma please response

Comment: @RahulSharma plz check the code now this is the real code i have written for the image binding

Comment: @RahulSharma   Iam giving the correect datasource, and the images are in images folder in my solution

Comment: @RahulSharma check the SS i have provided i tried to convert the url to byte

Comment: @RahulSharma File does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @RahulSharma not helping bro

Comment: @RahulSharma  url src is system.btye[]  and if i write this code (data:image/jpg;base64) it is showing this data:image/jpg;base64

Comment: @RahulSharma i have provided the code above already

Comment: https://youtu.be/SZOyiJPwj18  ---- please go throuth this tuturial i write the same code   @RahulSharma

Comment: @RahulSharma The code is same exactly the same.  Its jst that iam not uploading the image from anywhere, i have inserted the image in the table directly

Comment: @ShubhamRiyal Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042424/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-i , you are having the same problem it seems.

Comment: @RahulSharma yes this is the same issue. how it will be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding you case, you need to do the following:

When getting the `DataRow`, you need to cast it to `Byte[]` and convert it to a Base64 string like this:

```
dr["ImageFile"] = Convert.ToBase64String((Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageFile"]);
```

Once you have the Base64 string, then you can apply it to your control like this:

```
<img src='data:image/jpg;base64, <%# Eval("ImageFile")%>' />
```

Comment: Thanxxx Rahul for the code it worked